# how to calculate the differences of a list of pandas timestamps?

Tags: pandas

When I have a pandas timestamps like so:

```
list(uni_index)

Out[95]:

[<Timestamp: 2011-04-16 00:00:01>,
 <Timestamp: 2011-04-16 00:00:21>,
 <Timestamp: 2011-04-16 00:00:46>,
 <Timestamp: 2011-04-16 00:01:08>,
 <Timestamp: 2011-04-16 00:01:33>,
 <Timestamp: 2011-04-16 00:01:55>,
 ...
```

How would I get the differences of these time stamps?

I found a brute for it like so:

```
np.diff(uni_index.values.astype(int))
```

but it would be nice if it's possible to get back an answer in datetime.timedeltas directly from pandas. Maybe it is, I just haven't found it yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a pandas Series rather than a list, you can use its [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) method:

```
s = Series(uni_index)
s.diff()
```

For example:

```
In [45]: s
Out[45]: 
0    2012-02-01 10:00:00
1    2012-02-01 10:01:00
2    2012-02-01 10:02:00
3    2012-02-01 10:03:00

In [46]: s.diff()
Out[46]: 
0        NaN
1    0:01:00
2    0:01:00
3    0:01:00
```

Comment: hm, I could swear I tried that out, but maybe not. Thx! And it looks like you found a bug in stackoverflow's markdown code display.